# Getting Error in this program: Checking if two array equal?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

While compiling the program an error is popping up which I'm not able to figure out what it is: "No matching function call to _distance_fw(int&,int&)".
Here in this problem I'm trying to check if two arrays are equal in terms of the values they contain.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<int,int> bucket;
unordered_map<int,int>::const_iterator it;

int main()
{
    int T,N,val,counter;
    int def=1;
    bool bug;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    {
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&N);   //N is the size of array
            counter=N;
            bucket.erase(bucket.begin(),bucket.end());
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            //scanning the first array
            {
                while(counter>0)
                {
                    if(j==0)
                    {
                        scanf("%d",&val);
                        it=bucket.find(val);
                        if(it==bucket.end())
                        {
                            bucket.insert(val,def);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bucket[val]++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scanf("%d",&val);
                        it=bucket.find(val);
                        if(it!=bucket.end())
                        {
                            bucket[val]--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bug=true;
                        }
                    }
                    counter--;
                }
                if(bug==true)
                {
                    cout<<"0"<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(it=bucket.begin();it!=bucket.end();it++)
                    {
                        if(it->second!=0)
                        {
                            cout<<"0"<<endl;bug=true;break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(bug==false)
                    {
                        cout<<"1"<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the decision-making process that led to this particular indentation/formatting scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change

```
bucket.insert(val,def)
```

Into:

```
bucket.insert({val,def})
```

[std::unordered_map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) needs a `std::unordered_map::value_type` which in this case is `std::pair<const int int>`.

And please format your code better.

Comment: Thanks, It was helpful!